# Column highlight with Angular mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I would like to highlight my sorted columns for a better UI experience, but my problem is : mat-table is only triggering classes on the header of the table.

Mat table is working like that :

You click on a header cell to sort the table, a `mat-sort-header-sorted` class is added to the `div.mat-sort-container`. Problem is : this div is a child of the `div.mat-header-cell` and only this one.

Angular mat-table doesn't add anything in the other cells of the same column, which is anoying when you want to stylized the entire column.

So, is there a way to highlight a entire column with Angular mat table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you has the "propertie" of an

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
```

"active", so, you can, e.g. write

```
<td [style.background-color]="sort?.active=='id'?'red':null"..>
```

See the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmbppp?file=src/app/table-overview-example.ts)